# checking uploaded Microsoft office files for macros (in PHP or other)

Tags: php, security, file-upload, ms-office

I have a form in which a user is suppose to upload a microsoft office file such as: excel (.xlsx), word (.docx), power point etc.

I'm already using finfo to make sure the file types are office files:

```
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $type = finfo_file($finfo, $filepathname);
```

for security reasons I need to determine determine whether those files contain macros in them.
can that be done in PHP? is there a built in function for this in PHP?
I rather do this in PHP but if there's no way to do this in PHP, because it's on a linux server, I'll be happy to do this in linux command like "file".
I didn't see that "file" can do it either.

I read somewhere that if it's a file with an extension like: .docx, .xlsx (without the "m" at the end) than generally speaking it shouldn't contain a macro but I don't want to rely on file extension for security as this can be easily manipulated.

any suggestions?

Comment: Use a PHP-Excel library (google, there aren't that many) to open and read the file, and from there it's probably safest to create a new file and copy only the pure values from cell to cell. Basically, recreate the file from scratch with only explicitly supported structures. Maybe such library may have some "remove all macros" function, but that may still leave other things you'd rather not have. It depends on what exactly you do or don't want and use those files for.

Comment: is there something in the content of the file(s) (without the "m" at the end) in their extension that can indicate that it contains a macro ?

Comment: @john_black a bit late, but it's not about someone changing the file name or content type. The application (e.g., Word) is the one that will open that file. If it is a docx, it won't load macros, or will block them by default. In some cases, it can even simply not open the file.